# Standard way to sync sqlite data to online server using webservice

Tags: android, json, web-services, sqlite, synchronization

I have local sqlite storage for my app. Once the user enables online sync option the data syncs with my online server using Asp.Net webservice. For syncing i am concatenating all tables' data in a single string and then passing that string parameter to service.

Example : "table_name1$col1_value$col2_value$col3_value|table_name2$col21_value$col22_value$col23_value.."

Its really hard to manage sync status of each row using this approach. And somehow it doesnt looks like a good approach to me.

The other approach i tried and looks better than this is to pass List of tablename1, List of tablename2 objects in a single containg object or as different parameters.

I am sending data in JSON format.

What approach should i follow to pass the data to webservice(any better approach than these two). A optimal and standardized approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is use a time stamp to handle this.

1. Initial request to server with time stamp value 0.
2. Server will give the  all the data first time with Time-stamp.
3. Store the Time stamp to sharedpreferences.
4. In All next request pass the time stamp back to the server
5. Server will send only those data which are add/update/ after that
   given time stamp
6. That is it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to send all my offline tables' data in a single request to server. And i can get back the Ids of the rows successfully added to server. My point is should i send my table data in objects form or in concatenated string form ? And please tell how does this Time-Stamp helps in sync process.

Comment: JSON is best and light wait DataStructure widely used now a days.